# The import com.mongodb cannot be resolved - Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, mongodb, eclipse, maven, import

I am trying to setup a test connection to MongoDB. I am in Eclipse, using a Maven build. My pom file is below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br-uml-manager</groupId>
  <artifactId>br-uml-manager</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>compileId</id>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6.0-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mongodb-java-driver</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    
        
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
    
  </build>
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
</project>
```

I've added the dependencies. And this is my code:

```
package com.uml;
import com.mongodb.*;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

    }

}
```

I've tried changing the version of mongodb in the dependency part to 3.7. I'm using Java SE 1.8, and these are some settings for build path:

[image]

[image]

I honestly think the cause is related to another issue I was getting, when I was importing a PlantUML library "net.sourceforge.plantuml.SourceStringReader;"

But I'm not sure what exactly that issue is...

Comment: You can try using the latest of the MongoDB Java Driver (that would be v4.2). And see the Installation and Quick Start topics at [MongoDB Java Driver documentation page](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/)

Comment: @prasad_ I tried to run my project as a Maven build with both v4.2 and 3.7.1, and either time I got the error BUILD FAILURE with the log "Could not find artifact org.mongodb:mongodb-java-driver:jar:3.7.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue -- the problem was that I was I had entered the MondoDB dependencies under plugin